# Как связать Activity между собой в android studio

Tags: android, activity

Как можно связать `Activity` между друг другом?
К примеру у меня есть `MenuActivity`, в котором при нажатии на один из пунктов должно переходить на другую `Activity` из этого меню.

Answer (score 4):

Пример:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

[Тут подробнее](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)